# How to check if given argument for file reading is valid?

Tags: c

I am taking in an argument using fopen. What are some checks I can do to make sure that fopen actually takes in the string to a valid filename?

Comment: Don't; just try to `fopen` it. Anything else opens you to potential race conditions.

Comment: Do you want to make sure that the value being passed to `fopen` is `char*` ? Is that what you are asking ? And what do you meant by valid filename ?

Comment: Are you asking how to verify that a filename argument is an actual file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number one method is to try opening the file.  If `fopen()` returns NULL, there was an error.  Check the `errno` variable or function to find out the problem.

Trying to preprocess a file specification is an exercise in futility.  The operating system will do every relevant check for you, including those which are hard for you to do, like checking file protection ACLs, etc.

Comment: This also means that, even if you think you're just being thorough by pre-checking, the OS will do the same checks again and, most likely, some more checks you didn't think of.

Comment: It also avoids race conditions: you check for file's existence, and it's there, but it doesn't mean that it will be there when `fopen` is called (or the other way around).

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't clear, but if you want to know if the file name you have points to an existing file, you can use `access` ([Linux documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access)) ([Windows documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w06ktdy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)).